# java netbeans doesn't work from constructor

Tags: java, error-handling, constructor

My code under this text.My goal i have a text like this:

drunk//pepsi
drunk//cola
snacks//chips
tools//key
so on..

Firstly read all row by the readline.Before // ones to JLİST1.After // ones to JList2.When i try to run Program stuck.I think problem from constructor.How can i fix this.Ty for help

```
  /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package finalcalismasi1;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;

/**
 *
 * @author TOSHIBA
 */
class product{
    public String Group;
    public String Name;

}
public class vizesorusudeneme extends javax.swing.JFrame {
   ArrayList<product> productum=new ArrayList<product>();
        DefaultListModel model1=new DefaultListModel();
          DefaultListModel model2=new DefaultListModel();
    public vizesorusudeneme() {
        initComponents();

        try{
        Charset.forName("ISO-8859-9");
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("stok1.txt")));
        String line=br.readLine();
        while(line!=null){
            String[] urun=line.split("//");
            product pr=new product();
            pr.Group=urun[0];
            pr.Name=urun[1];
            productum.add(pr);          
        }
        for(int i=0;i<productum.size();i++){
            if(model1.indexOf(productum.get(i).Group)==-1){
                model1.addElement(productum.get(i).Group);


            }


        }
        jList1.setModel(model1);

        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }

    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jList1 = new javax.swing.JList<>();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jList2 = new javax.swing.JList<>();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jList1.addListSelectionListener(new javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener() {
            public void valueChanged(javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent evt) {
                jList1ValueChanged(evt);
            }
        });
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jList1);

        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jList2);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(28, 28, 28)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 68, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(105, 105, 105)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 61, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(207, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(48, 48, 48)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap(122, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jList1ValueChanged(javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent evt) {                                    
        // TODO add your handling code here:

        for(int i=0;i<productum.size();i++){
            if(jList1.getSelectedValue().equals(productum.get(i).Group)){
                model2.addElement(productum.get(i).Name);
            }
        }

        jList2.setModel(model2);

    }                                   

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(vizesorusudeneme.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(vizesorusudeneme.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(vizesorusudeneme.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(vizesorusudeneme.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new vizesorusudeneme().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JList<String> jList1;
    private javax.swing.JList<String> jList2;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: No proper english.

Comment: Could be.But not worst i think.

Comment: I think you need to add comment on above already asked question rather than adding new question. Already put question get more attension as compare to this new one....

Comment: I researched but didn't find anything same with my question.My problem exactly like this: I have a .txt file      x//xa y//ya x//xb  etc.Split each text and x and y to product.group.xa ya xb to product.name. Product groups add jlist1.Produt names add to jlist2(When any jlist element choice(when valuechanged is active)) prob u can figure out now

Comment: @VodkaMorello  your program enters infinite loop, try to replace the line where you define `line` string and next line following it with this `String line = null;
while ((line  = br.readLine())!=null)`

Comment: @VodkaMorello like this example http://pastebin.com/TAWrCxPi

Comment: Omg naruto ty so muchh.I didn't realize that mistake.